# Output index of ELKI

Tags: output, cluster-analysis, data-mining, dbscan, elki

I am using ELKI to cluster data from CSV file

I use

```
-resulthandler ResultWriter
-out folder/
```

to save the outputdata

But as an output I have some strange indexes

```
ID=2138 0.1799 0.2761
ID=2137 0.1797 0.2778
ID=2136 0.1796 0.2787
ID=2109 0.1161 0.2072
ID=2007 0.1139 0.2047
```

The ID is more than 2000 despite I have less than 100 training samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBIDs are internal; the documentation clearly says that you shouldn't make too much assumptions on them because their **implementation *may* change**. The only reason they are written to the output at all is because some methods (such as OPTICS) may require cross-referencing objects by this unique ID.

Because they are meant to be *unique* identifiers, they are usually continuously incremented. The next time you click on "run" in the MiniGUI, you will get the next n IDs... so clearly, you clicked run more than once.

The "Tips & Tricks" in the ELKI DBID documentation probably answer your underlying question - how to use map DBIDs to line numbers of your input file. The best way is to **if you want to have object identifiers, assign object identifiers yourself** by using an identifier column (and configuring it to be an external identifier).

For further information, see the documentation: https://elki-project.github.io/dev/dbids